# From filter diagram to state equation

Tags: filters

[image]

How did we end up with these state variables $Z_1(n+1)$ and $Z_2(n+1)$ from the filter diagram ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly it is that you don't understand.

Comment: @MattL. How exactly did we come to derive the equations from the filter, I do understand half of it is from the feedback part, and rest feed forward, but I am confused regarding the flow of signals thats yield the Z1(n+1) and Z2(n+1).

Comment: Some arrows would help in the diagram. Note that the bottom path goes from right to left. And the path between the adders is from left to right. A delay makes from $z_i[n+1]$ a signal $z_i[n]$ (and not the other way around).

Comment: @MattL. Makes sense, thank you for your time, I am beginning to understand it now.